# When should I be worried about rep increases?

Tags: support, up-votes

In the last few days, I've seen [an unusual pattern in my rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/143/wikis?tab=reputation): very many<sup>1</sup> (more than usual) of my questions have received a single upvote (but only a few answers).

It could look like the votes of a sock puppet (it isn't). Could it be interpreted by the Stack Exchange team like that? Do I need to worry?

(Or are they from multiple locations?)

<sub>1 Number of unique upvotes = 28, by my counting (from 9 - 24 October)</sub>

Comment: JOHNO! I think you should be ok, but I'll wait for a data guru/mod to answer

Comment: Very many? No, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) is very many. I don't see anything unusual except maybe that you're getting a high proportion of upvotes on old questions compared to old answers. There may well be someone gaming the Electorate badge as DVK suggests.

Comment: My bad. I have been avoiding those I think are bad questions, but most of those were weeded out long ago. And I didn't restrict them to one subject or to one questioner. If I've caused any problems, I am genuinely sorry. For what it's worth, I tried to find those with scores of 9 or 24, so you'd you'd get badges too.

Comment: @JohnO: no problem, extra rep is always welcome! I just didn't want the SO team to think I was sock puppeting! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At least one person on chat indicated that they were maxing out 40 votes-a-day working towards Gold upvoting badge in the last couple of weeks. This could very well be a side effect.**

Feel free to raise on meta or to mods if you get hit by a serial script reversal - they can verify if that was an actual active user and hopefully would look foavorably on restoring the upvotes in that case [ **UPDATE: As per Gilles' comment, they can not reverse** ].

Unfortunately, you can't do anything (short of this alert-in-advance meta post) to prevent this, since the serial script is 100% automatic.

Comment: Moderators can't do anything about serial script reversals (neither trigger them, nor undo them). As far as I know, there is no precedent for restoring the upvotes. Serial upvote reversal isn't just about reverting fraud, it's also meant to reverse fanboy upvotes.

Comment: See the last paragraph in my profile.